# postgREST can find relation

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

I'm trying to set up postgREST.  Have been following the tutorial at http://postgrest.org/en/v5.1/tutorials/tut0.html.  Here is what I see. First, the schemas:

```
entercarlson=# \dn
List of schemas
Name  |  Owner
--------+---------
api    | carlson
public | carlson
```

Then a table:

```
carlson=# \d api.todos
                                        Table "api.todos"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id     | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('api.todos_id_seq'::regclass)
 done   | boolean                  |           | not null | false
 task   | text                     |           | not null |
 due    | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "todos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Finally, some data:

```
carlson=# select * from api.todos;
 id | done |       task        | due
----+------+-------------------+-----
  1 | f    | finish tutorial 0 |
  2 | f    | pat self on back  |
(2 rows)
```

But then I get this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/todos
{"hint":null,"details":null,"code":"42P01","message":"relation 
 \"api.todos\" does not exist"}
```

Which is consistent with this:

```
carlson=# \d
Did not find any relations.
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS.  I don't see which database this schema belongs to

Comment: What value are you using for "db-schema" in the postgrest configuration file? It should be "api" to match where you're storing the tables. http://postgrest.org/en/v5.1/install.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're targeting the wrong database, check the `db-uri` config value and make sure this uri contains the `api.todos` table through `psql`.

Also, want to clarify that the `search_path` is modified by PostgREST on each request, so if you `ALTER` your connection user `search_path` it'll have no effect on the schemas PostgREST searches.